# C# Decimal to double?

Tags: c#, pow, numericupdown

Why can't I use `math.pow` with `numericUpDown` value? When I use this code:

```
a = (numericUpDown1.Value);
b = (numericUpDown2.Value);
m = Math.Pow(a, b);
```

I receive the following error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: You have to cast the values as double as `Math.Pow()` is expecting doubles - `Math.Pow((double)a, (double)b)` A simple google search would have quickly answered this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Math.Pow` has only one [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) - the one accepting two `double`s. Since you want to work with `decimal`s, you need to use explicit casts in both directions:

```
decimal m = (decimal)Math.Pow((double)a, (double)b);
```